# How to get the same output using multidimensional arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, list, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I'm wokring on my homework. My program is supposed to ask the user for a number of rows and columns and multiply each index of 2d array and then output the results.

My program kind of fulfils what it should do - the output is correct. However, I really do not know how to solve this using 2d arrays. Probably because I haven't met with them previously and we have just started using them in classes.

```
while True:
    try:
        num_row = int(input("Number of rows: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('Please enter an integer!')

while True:
    try:
        num_column = int(input('Number of columns: '))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('Please enter an integer!')

for rows in range(num_row):
    for columns in range(num_column):
        print(rows * columns, end=' ')
    print()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Python has three different common types of "arrays"--which do you want to use? There is the list of lists, which is built into the Python language. There is also the standard `array` module with an array type, but this is little used. Finally, there is the `numpy` third-party module with its `ndarray` type, often abbreviated as "array". This last is very popular for large-scale calculation work. If you tell us which you want (or if you don't know) we can help you better. Your output looks closest to the `ndarray`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to initialize your 2d array. Here is a your modified code:

```
while True:
    try:
        num_row = int(input("Number of rows: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('Please enter an integer!')
while True:
    try:
        num_column = int(input('Number of columns: '))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('Please enter an integer!')


# initialize the 2d array (tab) using a list-comprehension 
# e.g.: for 3 cols and 2 rows, You will have
# tab = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
tab = [[0 for c in range(num_column)] for r in range(num_row)]

# to create each value of the 2d array
for rows in range(num_row):
    for columns in range(num_column):
        tab[rows][columns] = rows * columns


# to print the value of a created 2d array
for rows in range(num_row):
    for columns in range(num_column):
        print(tab[rows][columns], end= " ")
    print()
```

Here is another compact version:

```
while True:
    try:
        num_row = int(input("Number of rows: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('Please enter an integer!')

while True:
    try:
        num_column = int(input('Number of columns: '))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('Please enter an integer!')


# initialize the 2d array (tab) using a list-comprehension 
# e.g.: for 3 cols and 2 rows, You will have
# tab = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
tab = [[0 for c in range(num_column)] for r in range(num_row)]

# to create each value of the 2d array and print it at the same time
for rows in range(num_row):
    for columns in range(num_column):
        tab[rows][columns] = rows * columns
        print(tab[rows][columns], end= " ")
    print()
```

Comment: Thank you very much!I guess, I understand it now, so you probably taught me how to use these 2D lists.

Comment: You're welcome. You can take a look on `numpy` module if you want to work will multiple arrays. This module is well suited!

Answer (score 1):

A 2D array is essentially arrays inside an array, e.g.:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'],
 ['d', 'e', 'f'],
 ['g', 'h', 'i']]
```

I think your solution is the most efficient, but if you wanted to use 2D arrays (usually 2D lists in Python), then you would create an 2D array of the dimensions inputted, then iterate through each row and item in that row, and multiply each pair of indexes.

Maybe something like these nested for loops:

```
for i,row in enumerate(array):
    for j,item in enumerate(row):
        print(i*j,end=' ')
print()
```